# Using pandas DataFrame, how to calculate the standard deviation between first row and each row after?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple `pandas.DataFrame`

```py
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation on a rolling basis, all starting from the first row. So it would be standard deviation from rows 1-4, then rows 1-5, then rows 1-6, etc. I could easily do this iteratively but I'd prefer to do it with pandas functionality.

The final output should be

```py
    A   Standard Deviation
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4   1.581
4   5   1.870
5   6   2.160
```

Is there an appropriate method to do so?

Comment: Can you double check and break down the computation? Your output seems shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`expanding.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.std.html):

```
df['A'].expanding(min_periods=4).std()
```

Output:

```
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3    1.290994
4    1.581139
5    1.870829
Name: A, dtype: float64
```